# c#: Type arguments cannot be inferred

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.7.1

I'm new to C#.  I'm trying to get a `List.Select` to work with async tasks, and I'm getting an error with the `Select` call.  The error says

> The type arguments for method 'IEnumerable System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(this IEnumerable, Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Here's my code:

```
var lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("");
lst.Add("");
var tasks = lst.Select(async x =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    throw new Exception();
});
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: It will work in .NET Core. Which runtime are you using?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. What .NET version are you running this on?

Comment: I agree about asking the .NET platform/version used. I have deleted my own answer, but I assume the asker compile his code on .NET Framework, because the error usually happens on .NET Framework.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.1

Comment: The simple answer is that your `Select` isn't returning anything, so the compiler can't determine what `T` should be. I'm not sure why you `throw new Exception();` but if you replace that line with `return x;` it should at least build.

Comment: I'm throwing the exception because what I'm testing is the exception handling of async methods inside a select. But you're right, I added `return x` and it works.

Comment: @ewok As long as there is a `return [value];` statement, then it will build, even if it's unreachable (i.e. an exception is thrown).

Comment: @ewok "testing is the exception handling of async methods inside a select"? Select does not execute anything... (just making sure you know)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov but `Task.WhenAll` does